# sharepoint 2013 online mime

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, mime-types, sharepoint-online

When I click on a link to a html file i've uploaded to Sharepoint 2013 ONLINE, it forces me to download it rather than opening it directly in the browser.  I understand this is because SharePoint Online is adding the header X-Download-Options:noopen and text/html isn't in the MIME types.

So I can download the html, and open it from my Downloads folder.  However it's, understandably not downloaded the images, etc referred to in the page, making it useless.

There's loads on google about Sharepoint and mime types (mainly relating to pdfs), but very little on Sharepoint 2013 ONLINE.  I have no way of administering the Site Collection of 'the farm'.

I've tried using Powershell, but all the Sharepoint specific features e.g. Get-SPWebApplication aren't available to my client PC.  I've tried Enter-PSSession to connect Powershell remotely, but it doesn't connect.

I'm new to Sharepoint Online and to Powershell and am really struggling with this.

Any solutions, tips or tricks appreciated.

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 1):

As for Powershell:
 you have a very limited number of cmdlets. Usually you differentiate between SP cmdlets (for server) and SPO cmdlets (for Sharepoint Online).
Here is a full list of cmdlets:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-help/introduction-to-the-sharepoint-online-management-shell-HA102915057.aspx

To connect to SPO you need the Sharepoint Management Shell and connect-sposervice:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161392

As for the initial problem:
have you checked with the site content types and site features if there's something that could help you?

Comment: Thanks arletka.  I've downloaded and installed Sharepoint Online Management Shell now.  I seem to need to 'Run as administrator', but that's no problem.

When running
    Connect-SPOService -Url https://blahblah.sharepoint.com -Credential ianh@blahblah.onmicrosoft.com

I got a "Current site is not a tenant administration site" error. Googled that and added -admin to url.

    Connect-SPOService -Url https://blahblah-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential ianh@blahblah.onmicrosoft.com

But I now get 

    Connect-SPOService : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Any ideas?

Ian

Answer (score 0):

Are you using site administrator credentials? 
Check in the Portal who is responsible for the site collection you are trying to access.

I am guessing you have one global admin responsible for everything and probably owner of all site collections. Use global admin to make sure. You can test credentials:

```
    $cred=get-credential
    connect-msolservice -credential $cred
    get-msoldomainverificationDns
```

Enter the domain. If it throws an error, these are not admin credentials.

Comment: Thanks arletka.
In theory I've got full admin rights, but maybe not!  I'll ask the other admin and see what he says.
I'll try your credentials test and come back to you.
Cheers
Ian

Comment: No problem, write if you need anything more. Pls also mark the answers if  you think they were useful

Comment: Hi arletka.  I've tried to run your credentials test from Sharepoint Online powershell, but I just get:

'The term 'connect-msolservice' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.'

Any clues where I'm going wrong? Ian

Comment: These are cmdlets for Azure Module http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj151815.aspx   You also need it for Office 365. From Azure Powershell run as administrator you should be also to open an SPO session

Comment: I've downloaded and installed the Azure Powershell stuff.  When I run your test credentials code with: 'get-msoldomainverificationDns -domainname https://blahblah.sharepoint.com' I get a domain does not exist error: 'get-msoldomainverificationDns : This domain does not exist. Check the name and try again.' Does this mean I don't have admin rights or is something else wrong? Ian

Comment: Hi Arletka.  Yes, I am using https.  I typed the url in my reply but it automatically displays as a link here!  I'm using'get-msoldomainverificationDns -domainname https colon slash slash blahblah.sharepoint.com' Thanks, Ian

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open HTML files directly from SharePoint Online. Here are a couple of workarounds that work out just fine.

1. Open the library in explorer view and then open the htm file from there.
2. Convert the HTML file into ASPX.